# Decompressing a S3 File in Stream using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I'm trying to read a .zip file from S3 into a stream in C# and write the entries back to to originating folder in S3.  I've looked at the myriad of SO questions, watched video, etc trying to get this right and I seem to be missing something.  I'm now farther than I was originally, but I'm still getting stuck.  (I really wish Amazon would just implement a decompress method because this seems to come up a lot but no such luck yet.)  Here is my code currently:

```
private async Task<string> DecompressFile(string bucketName, string keystring)
{
    AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
    Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream();
    string sourceDir = keystring.Split('/')[0];
    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest{ BucketName = bucketName, Key = keystring };
    try
    {
        using (var response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
        using (var arch = new ZipArchive(response.ResponseStream))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in arch.Entries)
            {
                fileStream = entry.Open();
                string newFile = sourceDir + "/" + entry.FullName;
                using (Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility tranute = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(client))
                {
                    var upld = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
                    upld.InputStream = fileStream;
                    upld.Key = newFile;
                    upld.BucketName = bucketName;
                    await tranute.UploadAsync(upld);
                }
            }
        }
        return $"Decompression complete for {keystring}...";
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ctxt.Logger.LogInformation($"Error decompressing file {keystring} from bucket {bucketName}. Please check the file and try again.");
        ctxt.Logger.LogInformation(e.Message);
        ctxt.Logger.LogInformation(e.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The error I keep hitting now is on the write process at `await tranute.UploadAsync(upld)`.  The error I'm getting is:

```
$exception  {"This operation is not supported."}    System.NotSupportedException
```

Here are the exception details:

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=This operation is not supported.
  Source=System.IO.Compression
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.get_Length()
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest.get_ContentLength()
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.IsMultipartUpload(TransferUtilityUploadRequest request)
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.GetUploadCommand(TransferUtilityUploadRequest request, SemaphoreSlim asyncThrottler)
   at Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.UploadAsync(TransferUtilityUploadRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at File_Ingestion.Function.<DecompressFile>d__13.MoveNext() in File-Ingestion\Function.cs:line 136

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    File_Ingestion.Function.DecompressFile(string, string) in Function.cs
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is there an `InnerException` on that `NotSupportedException`?

Comment: What's the full stack trace as well: do you have info on what method originally threw it?

Comment: The response is probably GZIP.  See following : https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/01/23/how-to-compress-and-decompress-files-with-gzip-in-net-c/?force_isolation=true

Comment: So if the files inside the .zip file are GZIP files then I have the potential to run into this issue?  I was going to try and preserve the GZIP compression as a lot of the AWS architecture works with  GZIP compression, but instead I would have to decompress the stream again?

Comment: The transfer utility is trying to get the length of the stream but that is not a supported operation by gzipped streams. You'll have to decompress it to a temporary location.

Comment: @William, jdweng has a reputation as a bit of a troll - their comments generally aren't related to the question being asked. Don't take what they said too seriously -- it's perfectly possible to preserve the gzip compression when uploading to AWS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that AWS needs to know the length of the file before it can be uploaded, but the stream returned by `ZipArchiveEntry.Open` doesn't know its length upfront.

See how the exception is thrown when `TransferUtilityUploadRequest.ContentLength` tries to call `DeflateStream.Length` ([which always throws](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Compression/System/IO/Compression/DeflateZLib/DeflateStream.cs,eef7efd116595198)), where `DeflateStream` is ultimately the thing returned from `ZipArchiveEntry.Open`.

(It's slightly odd that `DeflateStream` doesn't report its own decompressed length. It certainly knows what it *should* be, but that's only an indication which might be wrong, so maybe it wants to avoid reporting a value which might be incorrect.)

I think that what you need to do is to buffer the extracted file in memory, before passing it to AWS. This way, we can find out the uncompressed length of the stream, and this will be correctly reported by `MemoryStream.Length`:

```
using var fileStream = entry.Open();
// Copy the fileStream into an in-memory MemoryStream
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Position = 0;

string newFile = sourceDir + "/" + entry.FullName;
using (Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility tranute = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(client))
{
    var upld = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
    upld.InputStream = ms;
    upld.Key = newFile;
    upld.BucketName = bucketName;
    await tranute.UploadAsync(upld);
}
```

Comment: I didn't spell this out at the beginning, which maybe I should have, but what I was trying to avoid was holding the entirety of the file in memory.  Sometimes the files can be rather large so I was wanting to try avoiding doing that in the first place by using streams.

Comment: @William Your answer holds the entire *gzip-uncompressed* file in memory - so it's significantly worse! And just accessing a zip on the fly will end up holding it all in memory at some point anyway - zips are random-access, so it can't just throw away information, as you might decide to open an entry which is early on in `response`

Comment: I was curious if I was achieving my goal on memory with my method or not so I appreciate the heads up.  I did test your code and it works well while allowing me to maintain the gzip compression.  I also like that it is much more succinct and clean.  Thanks for the help @canton7!  I'll make this as the accepted answer.

Comment: If you want to avoid holding both the whole zip, and a file contained in that zip, in memory at the same time, and you trust the value of `ZipArchiveEntry.Length`, you could always create a `Stream` subclass which wraps the stream returned from `ZipArchiveEntry.Open()`, and makes the `Length` property return the value of `ZipArchiveEntry.Length`. That doesn't stop you needing to hold the whole zip in memory through, as you'll need to be able to seek around it to pull out the various entries. Plus, the directory which says what entry is where is normally stored at the end of a zip

Comment: Seems it is an issue with AWS Sdk, the moment you use MemoryStream it shot up the RAM size and hence the cost too. For file size say 780 MB, 2 GB RAM is used

Answer (score 0):

Could be faster and more clean:

```
using var fileStream = entry.Open();
using (var output = new S3UploadStream(_s3Client, "<s3 bucket>", "<key_name>"))
{
    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(output);
}
```

S3UploadStream class is taken from https://github.com/mlhpdx/s3-upload-stream